# VSCode Snippet Transform to uppercase inline with regex

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, storybook, code-snippets

I have the following javascript snippet for creating a React Storybook story within a file:

```
    "Create React Storybook Story": {
        "prefix": "rss",
        "body": [
            "import { ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.stories$/$1/} } from '../../components/${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\\/)*(.*)\\.stories\\.js/$2/}/${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.stories$/$1/}';",
            "",
            "export default {",
            "  title: '${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(([a-zA-Z]*)\\/)*([0-9]+-([a-zA-Z]*))\\/(.*)/$4/}/${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.stories$/$1/}',",
            "  component: ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.stories$/$1/},",
            "  parameters: {",
            "    layout: 'centered',",
            "  },",
            "  tags: ['autodocs'],"
            "  argTypes: {},",
            "};",
            "",
            "export const Default = {",
            "  args: {",
            "  }"
            "};",
        ],
        "description": "Create a story for a react storybook component."
}
```

As can probably be interpreted, I have my stories organized like:

```
  - src/
    - stories/
      - 01-atoms/
        - Something.stories.js
```

I would like the title of this story, when I insert the snippet, to be `Atoms`, rather than `atoms`. The regex transformation is: `${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(([a-zA-Z]*)\\/)*([0-9]+-([a-zA-Z]*))\\/(.*)/$4/}`, but this results in a lowercase first letter, as that's what's in the filename.

I tried adding `/uppercase` to the end of the regex, but to no avail. I've also tried adding `\u$4`, but this actually just outputs the literal `\uatoms`. How do I perform an uppercase against a regular expression transformation inline with the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was super close. It turned out to be:

```
'${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(([a-zA-Z]*)\\/)*([0-9]+-([a-zA-Z]*))\\/(.*)/${4:/pascalcase}/}'
```